# Prevent Image Pasting in RichText Component

Tags: images, block-editor

We have several blocks that are using the [RichText](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md) component. We would like to be able to prevent some if not all of these blocks from allowing pasted images.

Core is able to do this with their blocks. For example, if you copy and paste an image into the `core/button` block it doesn't do anything. But when I copy and paste an image into my custom button block it renders an image. I can't figure out what core is doing differently to prevent this behavior. What am I missing?